# JavaScript Queue

Tags: javascript, synchronized

I'm trying create an specific queue, where determined function run many times between intervals.

I already have something that works if the amount of items on queue are low, like 5 or 15 items.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('.log').html('');
    var loop = parseInt($('input[name="text"]').val());
    for (var i = 1; i <= loop; i++) {
      Sync.timeout(i, loop);
    }
  });
});

var Sync = {
  status: 0,
  timeout: function(index, indexs) {
    if (Sync.status === 1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        Sync.timeout(index, indexs);
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
    Sync.status = 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.log').prepend('[' + $.now() + '] ' + index + '/' + indexs + '<br />');
      Sync.status = 0;
    }, 5000);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 0.714em;
}
input {
  padding: 1px;
  width: 50px;
}
.log {
  border: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="text">Queue Size:</label>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="5" />
<a href="javascript">START</a>
<div class="log"></div>
```

My current problem is that if I have 20 or more items the sequence get crazy like this:

```
1/40
2/40
3/40
32/40
6/40
40/40
10/40
39/40
```

So, I'm not understanding why the javascript gets crazy with a high amount of items.

Alternatively, you can check the code [here (CodePen.io)](http://codepen.io/rochapablo/pen/NPNeLB).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I don't think that what you have right now would work as an actual queue. It will just fire off at random, first come first serve.

Comment: Rq 1) All the 1000ms delayed timer will be set to trigger at exactly the same time (with a 1ms accurate clock). 2) The order in which timer set at the same time will trigger is not defined by the specifications (or i couldn't see that they are https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout ).

Comment: But why not simply build a queue using an array? Then after the last log is completed. Simple pick the next from the queue, until the queue is empty.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is use this queue in $.ajax.
I have an array that need to be send and treat on success. And every thing must be done in the same order of the array loop.

I also have to consider the time of request, that could be diferent time for each item requested.

What is happen is that sometimes the order goes crazy and not all items from array are send.